# Splitting a path to a file name

Tags: zsh

In my zsh script, I would like to find out, whether my working directory starts with `/cygdrive/?/...` or matches exactly `/cygdrive/?` (where the drive letter (?) can be any letter different from the letter c), and if it does, retrieve into two variables the `/cygdrive/?` part and the remaining `/...`. Example: If my working directory is `/cygdrive/r/abc/xyz`, I would like to have the variable `head` set to `/cygdrive/r` and the variable `tail` set to `/abc/xyz`. If PWD is just, say, `/cygdrive/r`, the variable `tail` should be empty.

I prefer a solution using zsh internal commands only, i.e. without the need of spawning a process.

I came up with the following solution, which does the job, but I don't like it:

```
if [[ $PWD == /cygdrive/[abd-z]* ]]
then
  local head=${PWD:0:11}
  local tail=${PWD#/cygdrive/?}
  ....
fi
```

In particular, I don't like the calculation of head, with the hardcoded value of 11, and I'm wondering whether there might perhaps be a completely different approach, which would be more elegant.

UPDATE: I am aware that my `if` condition would also be true, if PWD is, for instance, `/cygdrive/foo`, but for my application, I don't consider this a problem. Of course if you can suggest a better alternative for writing the condition, which *exactly* does what I want, I appreciate any comment.

Comment: @Sparhawk and other closers. Please indicate what's "unclear" in that question so it can be clarified.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if [[ $PWD =~ '^(/cygdrive/[abd-z])(.*)' ]]; then
  head=$match[1]
  tail=$match[2]
fi
```

Same with globs:

```
set -o extendedglob
if [[ $PWD = (#b)(/cygdrive/[abd-z])(*) ]]; then
  head=$match[1]
  tail=$match[2]
fi
```

Globs also have the advantage of using `zsh`'s own pattern matching where `d-z` only matches on `defghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`, while `=~` would use your system's regexps where `[d-z]` may very well match on many more characters (like `é` or even sequences of characters like `dzs` in Hungarian locales). Doing a `set -o rematchpcre` would cause `=~` to use PCRE which are more reasonable in that regard.

To not match on `/cygdrive/foo`:

```
if [[ $PWD =~ '^(/cygdrive/[abd-z])(/.*)?$' ]]; then
  head=$match[1]
  tail=$match[2]
fi
```

With globs:

```
set -o extendedglob
if [[ $PWD = (#b)(/cygdrive/[abd-z])(/*|) ]]; then
  head=$match[1]
  tail=$match[2]
fi
```

Comment: Great, but one question for clarification: In your solution using extended globs, shouldn't it be `[[ $PWD == ... ]]` instead of `[[ $PWD = ... ]]`. From my understanding, using `==` in a conditional, causes the right side to be interpreted as a filename generation pattern.

Comment: @user1934428, `=` and `==` are strictly equivalent and both do pattern matching. The only case where they are different is with bash version 2.02 (and that version only). See [What is the difference between \[\[ $a == z\* \]\] and \[ $a == z\* \]?](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/56674) for details.

Comment: Right you are! My memory was tricking me. I should have read the zsh man page, where it clearly says about `=` vs. `==`: *The two forms are exactly  equivalent*.

Answer (score 2):

Since you already know how to fetch the suffix of your variable, you can remove it from the variable to have the prefix:

```
if [[ $PWD == /cygdrive/[abd-z] ]]
then
  local tail=${PWD#/cygdrive/?}
  local head=${PWD%%$tail}
  ....
fi
```

As for the condition, you can use regular expressions in Zsh:

```
if [[ $PWD =~ '^/cygdrive/[abd-z](/.*)?$' ]]
then
    tail=${PWD#/cygdrive/?}
    head=${PWD%%$tail}

    echo "head is $head"
    echo "tail is $tail"
else
    echo "no match"
fi
```